# Get innerHeight in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the inner Height in IE. My page content is long and browser has a scroll bar.

I got that using `window.innerHeight`.It worked on Firefox and Chrome but not on IE(tried on IE9)

Is there way to get it?

Refer the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m50Mg.jpg

**P.S.**

My problem was another thing. **My IE ran on *QUIRKS* mode**.

Both `$(window).height()` and `window.innerHeight` work when IE runs on Standards mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

or with jQuery:

```
$(window).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

**have you tried :**

```
window.height();//jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below example

```
$(document).height(); // Just returns the actual height of the conatiner

$(document).innerHeight(); // including padding but not border.

$(document).outerHeight(); // including padding and border. 

$(document).outerHeight(true);  // if wants margin height means Including margin, padding, border and height
```